# How to get image from plugin internal resources?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, swt

I'm trying to get an image file from my plugin resources using SWT `Image`

```
Image image=new Image(device,"icons/imagename.png");
```

The icons folder is in the classpath of the plugin but I still get an `IOException`.

Can you help me indicating what is the correct way of accessing an Image resource from internal resources of the plugin ?

Comment: are you using `java.awt.Image`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use something like:

```
String path = "icons/imagename.png";
Bundle bundle = Platform.getBundle("plugin id");
URL url = FileLocator.find(bundle, new Path(path), null);
ImageDescriptor imageDesc = ImageDescriptor.createFromURL(url);
Image image = imageDesc.createImage();
```

Don't forget that you must dispose an image when you are done with it.

Comment: FWIW: It might be a better idea to copy the image into your own plug-in, just in case the image is removed from a future version of the plug-in.

Comment: @david You still use the same code when the image is in your own plugin.

Comment: very true. I'm just cautioning against depending on a resource in another plugin that could change in the future.